# difference between Man-in-Middle and DNS poisoning attack?

Tags: security, networking, dns, man-in-the-middle

I read that there are two types of redirect attacks on DNS servers 
1) Man-in-Middle 
2) DNS poisoning

what is the difference between these two types ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network security and is not programming-related.

Comment: I didn't mention programming !!

Comment: Indeed, and thus your question is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

Man in the middle is to get informations exchanged by two users.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack

> [...] making them believe that they are talking directly to each other over
>   a private connection, when in fact the entire conversation is
>   controlled by the attacker [...]

DNS poisoning is done to alter the data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing

> [...] it is considered poisoned, and it supplies the false data to clients [...]

Comment: I guess the man in the middle may attack a dns request, which causes the redirect attack which the user faces, right?

Comment: @user2806799 It may be this way, or just using hardware injection point without DNS implication, I guess. (see : DNS poisinong is 'specific' to DNS)